# How to deploy Django 1.3 site on Python2.7 running on 64-bit Windows 7?

Tags: django, windows-7, 64-bit, python-2.7, web-deployment

mod_wsgi seems to be only available for win32.

I'm looking for a no cost solution.

Thanks!

EDIT: For Production environment

Comment: Is this for production or development?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See:

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Top search result returned by 'mod_wsgi win64' on Google.